# Is there a Javascript function to take an object as argument and return an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I desire to have a javascript function that can take an object with properties as an argument, process it and return the object's properties as an array of strings...
The code am trying so far is here but its printing out the entry name and the property name

```
let Southampton={
    name:"Southampton",
    founded:1900,
    stadium:"St. Mary's Stadium",
    points:36
}
function printObj(arg) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arg)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
}
function printObj(Southampton)
```

The code above is outputting

```
name: Southampton
founded: 1900
stadium: St. Mary's Stadium
points: 36
```

Can the function be extra modified to make it return this

```
Southampton was founded in 1900
```

Thank You for your assistance

Comment: You don't need a loop for something like this, just make your function return a string that uses the specific object properties you need `\`${arg.name} was founded in ${arg.founded}\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arg.map()` to return an array from calling a function on each entry.

```
function obj_to_array(arg) {
    return Object.entries(arg).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

To get the second message, you can't use a general purpose function like that, since it needs to format the string specifically for the `founded` property.

```
function when_founded(arg) {
    return `${arg.name} was founded in ${arg.founded}`;
}
```

If you really want them both in a single function, you can print the message before returning the array.

```js
let Southampton = {
  name: "Southampton",
  founded: 1900,
  stadium: "St. Mary's Stadium",
  points: 36
};

let Burnley = {
  name: "Burnley",
  founded: 1850,
  stadium: "Turf Moor",
  points: 33
};

let cities = [Southampton, Burnley];

function when_founded(arg) {
  return `${arg.name} was founded in ${arg.founded}`;
}

function obj_to_array(arg) {
  console.log(when_founded(arg))

  return Object.entries(arg).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
}

console.log(obj_to_array(Southampton));

console.log(cities.map(when_founded))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229426/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-is-there-a-javascript-function-to-take-an-object).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the index's of each word you could do something like this:

```js
let Southampton = {
  name: "Southampton",
  founded: 1900,
  stadium: "St. Mary's Stadium",
  points: 36
}

function printObj(arg) {

  let values = [];

  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arg)) {
    values.push(key);
    values.push(value);
  }

  console.log(`${values[1]} was founded in ${values[3]}`);
}
printObj(Southampton); // Southampton was founded in 1900
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function return `values`?

Comment: Hard-coding the indexes seems like a very poor idea, when you can just access the properties by name.

Comment: The OP's function just logs the data doesn't return it. Didn't want to change that.

Comment: But he asked how to change it to return an array of strings instead of printing them.

Comment: I'll make the edit to return the string as opposed to logging it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no build-in function for this.
If i understand it correctly, to achieve your goal you just need to use string interpolation to display parameters, like:

```
function printObj(obj) {
 return `${obj.name} is founded in ${obj.founded}.`;
}
```

Comment: He asked how to return an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

With Object.values() Method you could do the basic work as an oneliner. ( NO IE Support)

```
const valArray = Object.values(Southampton);

console.log(valArray);

console.log(`${valArray[0]} is founded in ${valArray[1]}`);
```